# File is Uploading to Cloudinary but can't see it on cloudinary though i have the secure_url from its response

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

here is my api code -

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(datauri.content, {
                    folder: 'Certificates',
                    use_filename: true
                   } , (error, result) => { //some code });
```

Am i missing something ? uploading directly works and image can be seen but when i am uploading it in a folder of a cloudinary it doesn't display, in chrome console it shows cannot read property of id and in network tab it shows no resource found, the good part is i am getting the url for the file uploaded and the file is present at that url, my only problem is i can't see it on cloudinary inside the specified certificat folder

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue with Cloudinary indexing of newly uploaded resources, folders and collections. Please follow/subscribe to the StatusPage for updates on the latest -
https://status.cloudinary.com/incidents/tfx2mbnzfwp3

Comment: The issue should now be resolved and assets re-indexed into the account again. May I please ask you to double-check?